# xxd not found in Recovery Mode, Mac OS X 10+

Tags: mac, bash, password, recovery

In Recovery Mode, I was trying to access my password hashes, except bash 3.2 returned `command not found` for `xxd`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't access my recovery partition now, but 'od' has a hex mode. Does recovery have that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recovery partition neither contains *xxd* nor *od*. Use the one installed to the main OS X volume by entering:

```
/Volumes/NameOfMainVolume/usr/bin/xxd
```

Don't forget to escape spaces in the name of your main OS X volume with a backslash. If you want to save something to a file also use your main volume. The Base OS X you are booted to is read-only and all the smaller r/w disks with less than ~50 MB are lost after a restart because they are in RAM.

Comment: Or quote the command line if it has spaces, but not both.

Comment: As a side q, what does xxd do?

Comment: @FlareCat, Read the `man` page for `xxd`. From `man xxd`: "xxd - make a hexdump or do the reverse."

Comment: @user3439894 oh sorry, completely forgot about man.